# Ajax and SweetAlert won't wait confirmation to continu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

I use nav-tabs, and I did a function to save (via Ajax) all informations every time you change tab, and I chose to put SweetAlert to confirm/inform that informations were saved.
Little issue is that the Swal shows up but we don't have the time to click or even read the message before the code goes on and the tab panel switch.

Here's my JS :

```
$('a:not(.disable-listen-change)').click(function(e){
    $('form').each(function(){          
        if($(this).data('changed') == 'yes'){
            var phpform = $('#formIs').val();    
            if(phpform == 'add'){
                conf = alert('Veuillez enregistrer la page avant tout autre modification');
                e.preventDefault();
                if(!conf){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            } else {                    
                var form = $(this).closest('form');
                var formdt = form.serialize();
                var id = <?=($id) ?? 0;?>;    
                $.post('<?=$this->url('ajax_products_edit')?>', {'form': formdt, 'id': id, 'phpform': phpform}, function(json){
                    console.log(json);
                    if(json['result'] == 'success'){
                        swal("Modifié", json.msg, "success");                       
                    }
                    else if(json.result == 'error') {
                        swal( "Oops", json.msg , "error");
                    } 
                    else {
                        swal( "Oops", 'Erreur lors de la modification' , "error");
                    }
                })    
            }    
        }
    });
});
```

I've seen other post talking about it, but everything I saw didn't work for me (except putting e.preventdefault, it let us the time to read and click, but after the tab don't switch. )

Thank you for your time